# Trouble installing ADB correctly, Kindle will not show up in device manager

Tags: rooting, adb, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

Currently using kindle fire HD 7.3.1 7" and would like to be able to add google play but when ever i try to install adb it says that I [correctly installed it.](http://gyazo.com/1b3275c7e0caf03d79448fda3720eddd)

I have both ADB turned on in the kindle and Allow installation of Applications.

Although this is what shows up in Device Manager:

[image: DeviceManager Screenshot]
<sup>DeviceManager Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Although this should be here there should also be another "Kindle" below "Keyboards".

Question. How can i get ADB to correctly install.

Comment: Actually, it shows in device manager (from picture provided by you). So what is your problem then?..

Comment: There should be a second "Kindle" showing below the keyboards.

Comment: No, there shouldn't be second kindle. Who has told you that?

Comment: Even still when I try and run the .bat's it does not show up under devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189488/debugging-android-apps-on-the-kindle-fire